# ImportError: cannot import name routes

Tags: python-2.7, flask, import

I am doing Miguel Grinberg's tutorial on Flask. I am having a strange issue: before, this wasn't happening, but now it is. When I try to run flask shell or simply run my application, I receive the following error:

```
NoAppException: While importing "app.microblog", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\blog\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "c:\Projects\Blog\app\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from app import routes, models
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name routes
```

I thought it might be a circular dependency problem, but that didn't seem to be the case. I've tried searching all over for the answre but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are importing the routes from app module within app module.. If you can share some more snippet, that would be helpful in understanding the problem.

But it seems,

```
from app import routes, models
File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name routes
```

In these lines, it says the exception is occuring in **from app import routes, models** line which is line 11 of app.py file.

So you are just importing the app module within app module.

Comment: Thanks Rishikesh. What snippets would be helpful for you to look at?

Comment: Another note: app.py is named __init__.py, and is located in the app folder. The app folder is located in highest directory of the project 'blog'. Blog contains app, migrations, and virtualenv, and then microblog.py and microblog.pyc - the name of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't import like the way you do already. Instead use the following:

```
import app
...
...
...
@app.routes('/something', methods=['DESIRED_METHODS']
def your_function():
    pass
```